# Understanding GCP IAM policies for various resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-cloud-iam

I want to list IAM policies or access levels for various resourses. I followed docs and I'm able to list it for projects. There are various resources and I'm somewhat confused with it.

1. Is all other resourses come inside the project? (Basically I'm confused with the chain)
2. If someone have access to project (read/write/anything else) then can they have access to resourses inside the projects?
3. If other resourses are independent then how to list their IAM policies? (For each individual resourse)

I'm using GCP Oauth2 API and would highly appreatiate if anyone at least answer the above questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is all other resourses come inside the project?**

Yes,

For a specific project, you can use search-all-resources to search all the resources across services (or APIs) and projects.
To use the number 123 to search every resource in a project:

```
$ gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=projects/123
```

**If someone has access to a project (read/write/anything else) then can they have access to resources inside the projects?**

Results from the above command are the resources in that project. If you have a user who has an owner role in the project then the user can manage roles and permissions for a project and all resources within the project. If a user has a viewer role then the user has permissions for read-only actions that do not affect state, such as viewing (but not modifying) existing resources or data.

Some resources also have separate permissions,a user can have permissions other than project level that is Individual permissions to the specific resource, by using them you can restrict the user to access projects but the user can access a specific resource.

Here you can find [Access control for projects with IAM](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-proj).

**If other resources are independent then how to list their IAM policies? (For each individual resource)**

Google has Predefined roles for every resource in the project you can filter out the specific resource by searching the resource in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined), those are predefined roles which can assign a user to the specific resource.

You can find more information in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access).

Answer (score 1):

The ORG, Folder, and Project are resources. They have an API to access IAM Policy Bindings. Cloud Storage, KMS, Compute Engine, Cloud Run, Functions, etc are also resources. They have an API to access IAM Policy bindings. Look up the API for each resource type.

In Google Cloud, many resources support IAM Policy Bindings but not all.

> Is all other resourses come inside the project? (Basically I'm
> confused with the chain)

Google Cloud resources belong to projects in almost all cases. Billing Accounts and Payment Accounts are examples that are separate.

> If someone have access to project (read/write/anything else) then can
> they have access to resourses inside the projects?

If as you say "read/write/anything else", then yes. If they have the correct IAM roles at the project level, they can access the resource. Since some resources also support their own IAM Policy Bindings, a user can be granted access to a resource at the resource level without having permission at the project level.

> If other resourses are independent then how to list their IAM
> policies? (For each individual resource)

You must access the resource's IAM Policy Bindings. Each resource that supports IAM Policy Bindings has a corresponding API to read/modify.

Note: resources are not independent. They are owned by a project in almost all cases as I mentioned previously.